# Blazor: Binding values to select/dropdown when using component tag helper in a Razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly

I'm building an app with Blazor Webassembly and I'm doing all the user management related bits of the system server side. I'm using the [component tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/component-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to enable me to use Razor components on my server side Razor pages, but I'm struggling to get my multiselect dropdown list working.

I've created a custom component (Dropdown.razor) that makes use of Radzen's dropdown component which looks like this:

```
@typeparam TItem

<RadzenDropDown AllowClear="true" AllowFiltering="true" FilterCaseSensitivity="Radzen.FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive"
                Multiple="true" Placeholder="Please Select" @bind-Value="@BindValue"
                Data="@Data" TextProperty="@TextProperty" ValueProperty="Id" />

@code {

    [Parameter] public IEnumerable<int> BindValue { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public IList<TItem> Data { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public string TextProperty { get; set; }

}
```

and then I'm pulling that through into my Edit.cshtml Razor page like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Line Manager(s)</label>
        <component type="typeof(Dropdown<UserDto>)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" param-BindValue="@Model.Input.SelectedLineManagers"
                   param-Data="@Model.Input.LineManagers" param-TextProperty="FullName"  />
</div>
```

This works in that it loads the component, pulls through a list of line managers and preselects any previously selected line managers (using data I've just input directly into the database). However, when I go to post the form, Input.SelectedLineManagers is always null - i.e. it doesn't appear to be binding properly when I update the dropdown.

What am I doing wrong? Using ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor Webassembly (.net 6).

Below is the code behind by Edit.cshtml file that gets called when the form is submitted.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string userId)
        {
            //code omitted for brevity
            var userManagerLinks = new List<UserManagerLink>();

            if (Input.SelectedLineManagers != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Input.SelectedLineManagers)
                {
                    userManagerLinks.Add(new UserManagerLink
                    {
                        UserId = int.Parse(userId),
                        ManagerId = item
                    });
                }
            }

            var userSub = HttpContext.User?.FindFirstValue("Sub");
            await _unitOfWork.SaveUser(userSub);
            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
```

Comment: How do you update the dropdown when you submit the form?

Comment: Hi Rena. Sorry, I'll edit my main post now to include the code.